# Add column in R with values based on variable 'names' of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

If we have a data.frame , say something like

```html
    ///// !col1!col2!col3
      ---------------
id123   1    0    0
      ---------------
!id435   0    1    0
      ---------------
!id777   0    0    1
```

I want to create a new column, newcol with values of variable names that have '1'

data want

```html
    ///// !col1!col2!col3!newcol
      ---------------------
id123   1    0    0   !col1
      ---------------------
!id435   0    1    0  !col2
      ---------------------
!id777   0    0    1  !col3
```

1) Are there ways to do in in base or plyr ?
2) (optional) how to adapt it if the id123 will have both values 1 in col1 and col2 ? how to 'add' these values, separated with comma in the newcol

```html
temp$col1 <- c(1,0,0)
temp$col2 <- c(0,1,0)
temp$col3 <- c(0,0,1)

temp<-data.frame(temp$col1, temp$col2, temp$col3)
```

Your support is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col` in `base R`

```
temp$newcol <- names(temp)[max.col(temp, 'first')]
```

---

If we have multiple 1's at the same row and what all the column names as a single string

```
i1 <- which(temp2 ==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
temp2$newcol <- NA_character_
temp2$newcol[unique(i1[,1])] <-  tapply(names(temp2)[i1[,2]],
         i1[,1], FUN = toString)
temp2$newcol
#[1] "col1"       "col1, col2" "col3"
```

This will also make sure that will assign only to rows where there are 1

#### data

```
temp <- data.frame(col1  = c(1, 0, 0), col2 = c(0, 1, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 1))
temp2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 1, 0), col2 = c(0, 1, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun !!!, thank for lighting fast response, what about the second point, if there are two 1 in same row, the above code give : only the first column names... if we do this, how to add the next one after a comma ? :

temp <- data.frame(col1  = c(1, 1, 0), col2 = c(0, 1, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 1))

temp$newcol <- names(temp)[max.col(temp, 'first')]

(optional) and if we check for values , if  we'll look for strings like "yes" instead of 1 .. ?

Answer (score 1):

additional option

```
library(tidyverse)
temp2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 1, 0), col2 = c(0, 1, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 1)) 

temp2 <- temp2 %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())

temp2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(col = str_c(name, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  left_join(temp2) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, nice approach too using some ninjutsu :)

Comment: hI again Yuriy, something is getting wrong with real data..., the code below works, but calculates wrong data, maybe there data problems ... 
No common type for `var1` <factor<85a9d>> and `var2` <integer>. ..

Comment: Can you give an example of data that is close to the real data structure? I will try to help.
Or maybe the @akrun example helped you?

Comment: I used this solution, dt$di <- apply(dt[-1], 1, function(x) max(names(which(x >0)))). but I did not find a way to add the comma stuff in the newcol if many 1 in a row... , other codes are giving errors

Comment: by not working i mean with the data I have, it works pretty well with the example code
The first code of akrun = not working
second code akrun = working but wrong results ( there are, 1,0 and NA's in the my data..) maybe you can check the code I have provided to tweak it to recognize if more than one 1 is present in the rows.. ?
your code not working ,  maybe there are ways to send you the mini cvs data. (7 rows)

Comment: Yurii, here what I get when i use your recommendation : rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Internal error: Trace data is not square.
Backtrace:
  1. (function (x, ...) ...
  2. rlang:::print.rlang_error(x)
 10. rlang:::format.rlang_error(x, simplify = simplify, fields = fields)
 12. rlang:::format.rlang_trace(trace, ..., simplify = simplify)
 13. rlang:::trace_format_branch(x, max_frames, dir, srcrefs)
 14. rlang:::branch_uncollapse_pipe(trace)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: Can you update the data example? Please use a minimally reproducible example.
To represent data, you can use `dput`